# How to access multi array value directly?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like array ( array 0 ('item1'=>1,'item2'=>3))....etc like so.

And I want to access say the value of item2 but I don't want to use array[0]['item2']...Is there another way to access it?  I just need 1 value so I don't think putting it in a foreach loop would be efficient..

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to use array[0]['item2']? Why not? And what language and platform is this for?

Comment: Hi, its for PHP..I was thinking what if I didn't know it was 0?  what if it is 1?

Comment: so the array is first indexed numerically, and then contains a sequence of items. right?  you want to get the first 'item2'?  or its known to be the only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices: if you know the row and column you want to access, then you can access it directly. If you don't know the row and column, then you'd need to use a foreach loop to find the item you want.

You can only access it directly if you know where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant `array ( 0 => array ('item1'=>1,'item2'=>3))`, you can use
array_values() to renumber the top level values. Then you know that the first value `('item1'=>1,'item2'=>3)` will be indexed by the key 0.